# Google translate on SD card

Tags: sd-card, google-translate

This question has been asked a lot before, but I can't find one from this year (or any answer that solves my problem)

I have just installed google translate on my new Samsung Galaxy J1 (SM-J100Y)  with Android 4.4.4

Is there a way I can move google translates offline translation packages to the SD card.  I tried copying the data folder, but it doesn't work, the app says it can't find any offline packages (after following these steps https://sites.google.com/site/galaxytinfo/saving-offline-languages-for-google-translate-into-external-sd)

Comment: I never read the details but I've heard that apps in Kitkat and above cannot write to external SD card under normal circumstances, so they rely on Internal SD card for everything. I suppose that's the reason why your app can't detect the folder since it is not looking in external SD card I believe. (It's hypothesis of mine). The method in that site would work nicely in JB or below.